# Sending login and passwords to another database on same server

Tags: php, mysql

I have read through the previous questions about updating 2 databases on the same server, I can not grasp the instructions and if they pertain to my case with passwords. I am looking to have one database updated from another with logins and passwords so customers can access both sites with the same login without registering on the second site.

Database_store1 - table_customer - (want these row columns sent to another database below on same server) Name, email, password

(Row would need to be created) Database_support2 - table_members - Name, email, password, and one column with a fixed value of "client"

I see there are password salts on both and a login key on the second...would these need to be added?

Comment: As both DB's are on same server, why not just write the code for both sites to login using the same database i.e. one of your databases.

Comment: I wish I knew home to write code...I would be willing to pay someone to code a solution to this.

Comment: Get thee behind me satan

Comment: If one of your sites already works, then you just need to do that same thing in the login process for both sites

Comment: I assume you mean change the form action to match the first one...I actually can't find where the second one is calling the form from. I will keep looking. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: No not necessarily. Change the login script to connect to the database holding logons in the second system. Validate login like normal. Then close that connection and open one to the apps real database